# Calculating driving distance using zip codes

Tags: php, distance, zipcode

How can I code something which'll calculate the **driving distance** between 2 zip codes within the USA in PHP. An API or web service that has SOAP or REST will also do.

But I understand GoogleMaps API can't be used because it violates the TOS.. So I need a way without using Google Maps, because I have no intention of using their maps, just calculate the distance.

Comment: a quick google search shows many sites violating that TOS...

Comment: Indeed, but my company will not be doing that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a whole lot out there that's free, other than Google Maps. The [MapQuest](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/directions-ws) API may give you what you need. Here's their [guide](http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/) to the service - it addresses getting driving distances/times between a set of points. Their [terms of service](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/terms-of-use) don't appear to require that you display a map, but take a look and see if that meets your needs.

Comment: I ended up using mapquest's API with a ZIP code to lat&long conversion DB, and got to say, works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps Distance API has this exact Functionality. You can get a return as either xml or json.

Here is the documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Here is a sample of the request url : 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false

One nice thing is you dont have to calculate the long/lat first

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/ ... I dont see any TOS issues but maybe I'm missing something